# How to construct a SoQL where clause on a text column using <= operation?

Tags: socrata, soda

I get an Unrecognized arguments error when trying to apply a <= operation on a SoQL text field. Any help is very much appreciated.

I have tried to apply several different filters on this text field but only the = operation works. When I try any other I get an Unrecognized arguments error.

For example:
https://data.sfgov.org/resource/bbb8-hzi6.json?start24=10:00 (works fine)
but 
https://data.sfgov.org/resource/bbb8-hzi6.json?start24<=10:00 (fails)

According to the documentation here https://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/text.html#, <= evaluates strings that are alphanumerically before or equal. I would expect these operations to work on text strings as stated.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but am digging into this and have some progress. I used a separate data set with a clear numeric column to test. I found the less-than operator (`<=`) behaved poorly without the `$where` statement. That is, `https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xzkq-xp2w.json?$where=typical_hours%3C=20` worked where as `https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xzkq-xp2w.json?typical_hours%3C=20` did not. However, this doesn't resolve your issue, but is noteworthy.

Comment: I would recommend that you reach-out to support@socrata.com on this. It does not appear that the API is behaving as documented. On the same data set, a text data type (but follows more traditional numbering) does not work `https://data.sfgov.org/resource/bbb8-hzi6.json?block%3C=4807`. Other permutations also do not work.

Comment: @TomSchenkJr thank you for looking into this. My original url actually does include the where clause however it was fairly complex so I simplified it for the example. I am new to SoQL so I thought there might be type casting or something else I was missing but I believe you are correct that the API is simply not behaving as described in the documentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Socrata API uses regular GET parameters. In your example, you're performing [simple filtering](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/filtering.html), which allows you to just perform exact matches.

```
https://data.sfgov.org/resource/bbb8-hzi6.json?start24=10:00
```

- `start24=10:00` has the GET parameter `start24` with a value of `10:00`

However, in your example with `<=`. That means something entirely different in the URL world; this means:

- `start24<=10:00` has the GET parameter `start24<` with a value of `10:00`.

Since you can't use any other operators such as `<=`, Socrata uses SoQL queries where special keywords start with `$`; e.g. `$where`.

```
https://data.sfgov.org/resource/bbb8-hzi6.json?$where=start24<="10:00"
```

Now this gets translated to:

- `$where=start24<="10:00"` has the GET parameter `$where` with a value of `start24<="10:00"`

Now, **this** Socrata can handle and will return your results.

Comment: Wow this works great! Thanks for answering and clarifying how to properly construct the where clause.